# SQLiteConstraintException?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Good morning, I have a problem, I created my `sqlite` `database` and it worked correctly without problem, and when entering data my bank is not giving a problem:

```
11-24 09:08:00.686 23239-23239/com.crudhightech.livros/System.out:
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: NOT NULL constraint failed: LISTA.DATA (code 1299)
```

method:

```
public void inserir(Livros livros)
{
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put("NOME", livros.nome);
    contentValues.put("PAGINAS", livros.paginas);
    contentValues.put("DATA", livros.data);
    contentValues.put("HORAS", livros.hora);

    conexao.insertOrThrow("LISTA", null, contentValues);
}
```

help me

Comment: Well, it does tell you everything. The Column `DATA` is marked as `NOT NULL` in the database and you try to put a null value into it, i.e. `livros.data` is null.

Comment: Okay, but I'm using this form to get the EditText field:
Scenario:
I use a dataPicker where it selects a data and it throws an EditText to date, and to get the value of this attribute field in a variable
data = (EditText) findViewById (R.id.date);
and play the data value without bank.
For what reason would it return me void?